# Calling service method and using it in the interceptor correct

Tags: angular, service, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors

My idea was to create one service method called loggedIn() which i want to call in the interceptor.
The loggedIn() service method should deliver a valid token which is available in the localStorage. In addition to the existence i want to check the validity of that token bei calling the verifytoken API from the server. The post call in the verifytoken Method within the service will do that.

As you can see in the code that i am calling the verifytoken service method within the loggedIn(). Is this a valid approach to call incident methods of the same service ?

As the loggedIn() will deliver the verifytoken result async, is there a need to subrcribe to loggedIn() service method when calling it in the interceptor ?

in my service:

```
       loggedIn(): string{
          let tok = localStorage.getItem('token');
          if (tok=== null || tok === undefined || tok === ""){
            return "";
          }else{
            //return tok;

            this.verifyToken(tok).subscribe(
              res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.success);
                return tok;
              },
              err => {
                console.log(err);
                return "";
              }
            )  
          }  
      }


      verifyToken( tok: string ){
          let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': tok });
          let options = { headers: headers };
          return this.http.post<any>(this.verifyUrl, "", options );
      }
```

In my interceptor:

```
    intercept(req, next){
      //Interceptor ausschliessen
      const exclude = "/verifytoken";
      console.log('Exclude' +req.url.search(exclude));
      console.log('Req '+req.url);

      let tokenizedRequest = req;

      if (req.url.search(exclude)===-1){
        //req clonen und mit header anreichern
        let mytoken = this.authServ.loggedIn();
        console.log('Token im Intercept '+mytoken);
        tokenizedRequest = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: mytoken
          }
        });      
      }
      return next.handle(tokenizedRequest);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any problem. Because _loggedIn()_ won't return anything until the _verifyToken_ returns a subscription. Is it working as expected?

Comment: Nope when i log the interceptor the mytoken variable is undefined. Could it be that this.authServ.loggedIn() will deliver the value at a later time ?